# How to determine if a Javascript prototype function exists

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I know I can run the following to determine if a normal Javascript function exists:

```
if (typeof yourFunctionName == 'function') { 
  yourFunctionName(); 
}
```

How does this work when I have the following:

```
Interface.prototype.yourFunctionName = function() { //ok };
```

Comment: `typeof Interface.propertype.yourFunctionName === 'function'` ???

Comment: propertype? you mean prototype?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply check `typeof Interface.prototype.yourFunctionName === "function"`, like so:

```js
function Interface () {
  this.a = "foo";
  this.b = "bar";
}

Interface.prototype.yourFunctionName = () => "baz";

console.log(typeof Interface.prototype.yourFunctionName === "function");
```